# Division by zero warning when divisor is "0.0"

Tags: php, division

I'm reading data from a text file and performing some basic math.   This is how things should work:

```
// no warning, expected result N/A
$dividend = 100;
$divisor = 0.0;
if (!empty($dividend) && !empty($divisor))
{
    $quotient = $dividend/$divisor;
} else {
    $quotient = 'N/A';
}
echo $quotient;
```

This is how things are actually happening.

```
// yeilds division by zero warning
$dividend = 100;
$divisor = '0.0';
if (!empty($dividend) && !empty($divisor))
{
    $quotient = $dividend/$divisor;
} else {
    $quotient = 'N/A';
}
echo $quotient;
```

I'm getting a division by zero warning when a value in the text file is read as '0.0', which `empty()` sees as non-empty, when it actually empty.

What's the best way to test that '0.0' is actually 0?

Comment: use http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to cast to float (or use `floatval()`) in your condition statement.  This leaves your values untouched in case you need other data from your variables, such as trailing text:

```
$dividend = 100;
$divisor = '0.0';
if ((float)$dividend && (float)$divisor) //both are non-zero
{
    $quotient = $dividend/$divisor;
} else { //one or the other are zero
    $quotient = 'N/A';
}
echo $quotient;
```

However consider only checking `$divisor` for zero.

Answer (score 3):

Typecast `$divisor` to float: `$divisor = (float)'0.0';`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `(double)` ? Rather than `(float)` ? Edit: both seem to work, nevermind.

Comment: @ɴᴀᴛʜ That depends on how much numbers after the decimal he needs. Float - 32 bit (7 digits), Double - 64 bit (15-16 digits)

Comment: @Daan In PHP, `(double)` and `(real)` are both aliases for `(float)`. PHP only has one float type.

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to an int;

```
$divisor = (int) '0.0';
```

Comment: Why int? What happens if `$divisor` is 0.4?

Comment: Sure, it could be, but it could also be "Mushroom". Truth is, we don't know whats causing `$divisor` to be `"0.0"` in the first place. Nor the specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

i think quotient should be zero if divisior is zero.
So you get a result in the following operations instead a N/A.

I always resolve it like this:

```
$quotient = ($divisor == 0) ? 0 : ($divident/$divisor);
```

it should work for `"0.0"`, too.